# Please help me understand grep and fgrep

Tags: unix

I am trying to grep a list of IDs present in file1 from file2

I write:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

The command gets stuck as if perpetually in the run phase.

Then I try:

```
fgrep -f file1 file2
```

This works in a flash. 
The man page of grep says that fgrep is same as "grep -f". But then how come I get no output for "grep -f"

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You'd be better off posting on superuser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cite the man page incorrectly! What is written there is this:

> fgrep is the same as `grep -F`

Note the *uppercase* `-F` which is quite different to `-f`!